The returned type 'List<int>' isn't returnable from a 'int' function, as required by the closure's context.: In Flutter app
I am creating a Wake on Lan app with Flutter, but I cannot resolve an error when creating a packet.
  void sendMagicPacket(String macAddress, String subNetMask) async {
    final List<int> macBytes = macAddress.split(':').map((e) => int.parse(e, radix: 16)).toList();
    final List<int> packet = List<int>.filled(6, 0xFF) + List<int>.generate(16, (_) => macBytes).expand((x) => x).cast<int>().toList();
    final RawDatagramSocket socket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
    socket.send(packet, InternetAddress(subNetMask), 9);
    socket.close();
  }

The returned type 'List<int>' isn't returnable from a 'int' function, as required by the closure's context.

.generate(16, (_) => macBytes)
                     ^^^^^^^^

The returned type 'int' isn't returnable from a 'Iterable<_>' function, as required by the closure's context.

.expand((x) => x)
               ^

How can I fix this?
I tried using things like x as int instead of .cast<int>() to fix the type error, but I got the same error.

List<T>.generate is used to generate the elements of the list.  The callback therefore needs to return a T.  As written, your callback to List<int>.generate returns macBytes (which is itself a List<int>) 16 times.  Is that what you want?

Here's what is happening, mackBytes is of type List<int> already. And List.generate is creating 16 other mackBytes into a list. Considering that mackBytes is a list already, and 16 of its kind is created, the result of generating 16 more becomes a list of List<int>, which is List<List<int>>
Below is the fix. You can also choose to remove the explicit List<List<int>> casting and simply use List.generate and it will work just the same.
//With explicit casting
final List<int> packet = List<int>.filled(6, 0xFF) + List<List<int>>.generate(16, (_) => macBytes).expand((x) => x).cast<int>().toList();

//Without explicit casting
final List<int> packet = List<int>.filled(6, 0xFF) + List.generate(16, (_) => macBytes).expand((x) => x).cast<int>().toList();

